# C2D messages to IoT Hub with Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-hub

Is there any possibility to send Cloud2Device message to an IoT Hub with Java by using MQTT as protocol?

I use ServiceClient from library: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/main/service/iot-service-client/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/service/ServiceClient.java and there it's impossible using MQTT, only AMQPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive Cloud2Device messages on your device, using the **Device SDK**, if you are connected over MQTT, AMQP or HTTPS.

In order to connect to your IoTHub from your solution back end, using the **Service SDK** to send cloud-to-device messages to a single device you will need to use AMQP or AMQP over Websockets.

[image]

> **Service endpoints.** Each IoT hub exposes a set of endpoints for your solution back end to communicate with your devices. With one
> exception, these endpoints are only exposed using the AMQP and AMQP
> over WebSockets protocols.

Ref: [Reference - IoT Hub endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints)